# Register targets for EC2 Target Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I am currently dabbling in deploying to AWS Fargate.

I followed the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N4e-Q7SnDI to create my VPC

Once created, I followed these tutorial here https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/deploy-docker-container-as-serverless-architecture-to-aws-fargate-1121bafa1d8c. I was successfully able to create a load balancer with services that is running two tasks simultaneously. But the issue I am facing is I can't accept the service.

When I go to the load balancer url, I am faced with a 503.

I've googled and I read it could be related to load balance listener and registered targets.

I do have a listerner at port 80 and it forwards to a target group
[image]

When I look into the target group, there's actually no registered targets. Could this be why and if so, what do ip's do I add for the target groups?

[image]

My subnets are as followed

- my-vpc-subnet-public1-us-east-1a  IPv4 CIDR 15.0.0.0/20
- my-vpc-subnet-public2-us-east-1b  IPv4 CIDR 15.0.16.0/20
- my-vpc-subnet-private1-us-east-1a IPv4 CIDR 15.0.128.0/20
- my-vpc-subnet-private2-us-east-1b IPv4 CIDR 15.0.144.0/20

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a load balancer, then you need to be configuring an [ECS Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html) to run your ECS/Fargate tasks. The ECS Service will handle starting your Fargate task(s) and also registering each instance of the task with the load balancer's Target Group.

Comment: HI @mark B, I actually am. It spins up two instances and both tasks are running. I followed the tutorial here https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/deploy-docker-container-as-serverless-architecture-to-aws-fargate-1121bafa1d8c 

The issue at hand is I cannot get to my instances that are spinning via load balancer URL.

Comment: Did you configure the ECS Service with knowledge of the load balancer? There's a lot of details missing from your question so I'm just having to guess at what may be the issue, but it sounds like you didn't configure the ECS service to actually know you have a load balancer it needs to register tasks with.